# Symfony2 standalone HttpFoundation component performance loss

Tags: php, performance, symfony, symfony-http-foundation

I'm currently developing a base application for my projects and something doesn't seem right.

First of all, I'm using PHP 7, Apache.

Composer is first called, it does its magic and all the goods. Then I register a Container (Illuminate) and at this point, the request is finished at about 8-11ms.

Now, when I add the `HttpFoundation` component to the app, the performance loss is huge, jumping from 8-11ms to a staggering 80-95ms.

The pieces of code related to the `HttpFoundation` component are presented below. It's nothing too complex; barely a few lines of code taken straight off the Symfony documentation.

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$input = $request->get('name', 'World');

$response = new Response();
$response->setContent('Hello, ' . $input . '!');
$response->setStatusCode(200);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
$response->send();
```

PHP info:
http://pastebin.com/3kgAJ635

After conducting a small test on the same component alone (composer + HttpFoundation), the results yield an average of 60ms. What is going on with Symfony's standalone components?

Comment: your `phpinfo()` can be helpful

Comment: @Federkun Added :)

Comment: install `php7.0-opcache`

Comment: @Federkun I honestly don't believe this is the reason for this, it should have decent performance on a clean standard PHP installation with no additional addons.

Comment: Chop the question in half.  Replace the $request and $input lines with $input = 'Hello'; and see what happens.  I suspect however that you have other stuff going on.